# Convenient FLAG for limit of a sequence

Tags: c, sequence, flags

I wrote a function that returns the limit of a sequence if it exists.

I would like to return a flag when the sequence doesn't converge (infinite limit).

How can I define this flag? I can't choose a random value because there is a probability that this value equals the limits of the sequence, so there will be aùbiguity.

thanks.

Comment: What type are you returning?  Could you return a struct that contains a boolean and the limit value?

Comment: What's the domain of your function? Some floating-point type? Try NaN then. Otherwise, what about using `errno`?

Comment: @Deduplicator the sequence values are of type double.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I need to return a double if the limit exists and some FLAG indicatng that it doesn't converge if not.

Comment: You know, just return +/- infinity if it goes to that one, and NaN if does not converge nor goes toward either. The caller can use the `isfinite` macro to determine if it converged.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't care if it is infinite value or not. I just want to show that it doesn't converge. Is NaN of type double?

Comment: There are NaN values of type double, float, long double... And `isfinite` returns whether it's a normal or sub-normal number, which means neither an infinity nor a NaN.

Comment: @Deduplicator:what about returningg a struct:containing a boolean (converge or not) and a double(limit f exists and NAN otherwie). ?

Comment: Why a struct with a boolean, if you can fit it all into the `double`?

Comment: @Deduplicator so, NAN if doesn't converge and the limit if it converges. and then i test the return value. if(isnan() then.. Is this ok?

Comment: Sure, if you either never return infinities or accept them as result. Otherwise, I mentioned `isfinite`...

Comment: @Deduplicator:Can you please write the code how to return a NaN directly from a function, I couldn't find an example on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `NAN` to signal a special answer is easy use (as suggested by @ Deduplicator).

```
double find_limit() {
  double limit = ...
  if (limit_not_found) return 0.0/0.0;  // Form NaN or use a macro/constant here
  return limit;
}


void foo() {
  double y = find_limit();
  if (y != y) puts("No limit found");  // NaN is not even equal to itself
  else The_HappyPath();
}
```

Comment: we could just do: return nan(""); and then use the function isnan(x) to test.j

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html), you will note there are macros for `INFINITY` (and thus `-INFINITY`) and `NAN` (not a number). You might choose to return the limit to which the sequence converges, or (e.g. for the sum of `x`) `INFINITY`, or (e.g. for the sum of `-x`) `-INFINITY`, or for (e.g.) `sin(x/4)` or `((x%2)*2)-1)` `NAN` (as the sum never converges).

If you don't like this, how about returning an integer to say whether it converges, and the limit in the address supplied by a parameter, like this:

```
int
converges (double *limit)
{
    if ( ... it converges ...)
    {
        *limit = whatItConvergesToo;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Or if you don't like that, define a `struct` or a `typedef struct` and return that:

```
typedef struct limit
{
  int converges;
  double limit;
} limit_t;

limit_t
findlimit ()
{
    limit_t l;
    if ( ... it converges ...)
    {
        l.limit = whatItConvergesToo;
        l.converges = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        l.limit = 0; /* be nice */
        l.converges = 0;
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: @Deduplicator: out of interest, whilst I agree `sumof(sin(x/4))` never converges, `sumof(sin(pi.x/4))` rather more obviously does not converge. So why the change? I suppose I should have picked `sumof(sin(pi.x/2))` which is even more obvious (0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, ...)

Comment: @Deduplicator - ah yes, slipped from C to math! sorry.